# JScript REST API: read a paginated list

Tags: api, rest, jwt, jscript

In JScript I need to read a list of books from a web server that has a 2-step authentication i.e. user + password and token afterwards - once you call an IP address you get a token in response which needs to be used in a header for books (Authorization; Bearer + token). Server is supposed to respond with a paginated list of books

```
[{"book_Id": 1,"book_Name": "AAA","book_Year": 2021}].
```

Path is "GET /book", parameters are: "Page" and "Size". I've managed to call the server and get token  in reponse:

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/authenticate?username=XXX&password=XXX", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var token = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).token
```

and tried to use it

```
var header = xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(header.responseText)
```

but got empty response and got stuck. I'd very much appreciate being moved on with how to read the list.

***Edit***

So I've added new object and now get status 404 error Not Found. Is there some error in the coding yet?

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/authenticate? 
username=XXX&password=XXX", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var token = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).token

var xmlhttp2 = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
xmlhttp2.open("GET", "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/book?limit=1", false);
xmlhttp2.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
xmlhttp2.send();
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(xmlhttp2.responseText)
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `header.responseText` ?

Comment: I do use xmlhttp.responseText to get token (var token = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).token) but then, I assume, must get another response with books data (so tried with header.responseText). I don't know what should be the next steps after getting token.

Comment: you should create a new xmlhttp object for each request, and get the response in the same way for each request.

Comment: I've added new object but there still something wrong - I get status 404 error Not Found (see Edit bit in original post).

Comment: 404 is progress. But it probably means the url you use is wrong? Curious also why are you using jscript? I thought that jscript was long dead.

Comment: Well, it's not that dead :-) I need to use it as a built-in script and only JScript and VBScript are available. Putting aside wrong url, are these lines correct?  xmlhttp2.open("GET", "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/book?limit=1", false);
xmlhttp2.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)

Comment: Yes this all looks correct to me.